# Why am I Blocked from accessing a same-origin frame using "window.opener"?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, web, https

I'm using Google Chrome and Adblock Plus.

Firstly, I opened `https://www.google.com.sg/` with Chrome and then open a console and input `window.open("https://www.google.com.sg/")` in the console.

Then a new window will appear. I input `window.opener.document` in the new window's console, but it throws an error:

> "Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com.sg" from
>   accessing a cross-origin frame."

I am quite confused because I'm using same-origin frame (Both window are from the same origin "https://www.google.com.sg") instead of cross-origin frame.. Why does the brower still complains about the Security Error?

Comment: I've just tried the same thing in firefox and it worked fine, which suggests chrome has extra inbuilt rules when dealing with google urls. what happens if you do it on a non-google domain?

Comment: @atmd For non-google domain, it is still blocked. I think it might be related to pop-up blocking function of Google Chrome..

Comment: Any plugins installed??

Comment: I tried ur code on chrome 31, and it works fine to me, other then it blocked my popup, which i manually allowed. after that i tried to access parent window using window.opener.document, it didn't gave me any error.
try to reset your browser setting to default.